# How to check if a bounding box is over a AOI and when it leaves. OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, intersection

So what I am trying to do is use OpenCV to detect the boxes and make and Area of Interest. When a box goes over a AOI it will count it as one use. This works fine but it keeps adding the usage for each frame. I only want to do this once while there is a usage detected.

So what I do here is:

1. Find the contour from background subtraction. Works
2. Get the bounding boxes for each blob detected. Works
3. Loop over each AOI box and use a Intersection over Union to see if
   there is any overlap.
4. I set the counted boolean in the AOI list to True. Only if it is
   False to begin with.
5. I ignore it if its been counted
6. If there is no intersection over union then I set the counted to
   False.

What goes wrong here is that it either keeps counting usage for every frame or it will only count it once and never again. I want to count it for each unique usage and not for every frame. This is what I have so far.

```
 # # loop over the contours
    for c in contours:
        # Filter out the blobs that are too small to be considered cars.
        contours = filter(lambda cont: cv2.contourArea(cont) > 30, contours)
        # compute the bounding box for the contour
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        #Find each Area Of Interest usage
        #detectUsage(area_of_interest, c, frame)
        for aoi in area_of_interest:
            #Check if there is a overlap between the detected contour and AOI
            if gvp.machineUseCheck(c, aoi[1]):
                print("{} in use".format(aoi[0]))
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (222, 150, 1), 2)
                if aoi[2] == False:
                    aoi[2] = True
                    print("{} set to True".format(aoi[0]))
                elif aoi[2] == True:
                    print("{} Already true".format(aoi[0]))
            elif gvp.machineUseCheck(c, aoi[1]) == False:
                aoi[2] = False
                print("{} not in use".format(aoi[0]))

        #Get all the centers for the bounding boxes
        center = (int(x + w / 2), int(y + h / 2))
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

Comment: So the image processing part of your programs is working fine but there is some logical bug in this, I would like you to re-frame this question by keeping the `OpenCV` part out of context. Try to create another minimal script and try fixing the behaviour there it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out all I needed to do was reorganize the for loop a bit.

```
        for aoi in area_of_interest:

        cv2.putText(frame, "AOI Value:{}".format(aoi[2]), (10, 150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6,
                    (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "{} Count:{}".format(aoi[0], str(aoi[3])), (10, aoi[4]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.6, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        i = 0
        for c in contours:
            # Filter out the blobs that are too small to be considered cars.
            contours = filter(lambda cont: cv2.contourArea(cont) > 30, contours)
            # compute the bounding box for the contour
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            center = (int(x + w / 2), int(y + h / 2))
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            if gvp.machineUseCheck(c, aoi[1]):
                if not aoi[2]:
                    aoi[2] = True
                    aoi[3] += 1
                cv2.putText(frame, "Machine IN USE:", (10, 130), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6,
                            (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (222, 150, 1), 2)
                break
            elif i == len(c):
                aoi[2] = False
                break
            i += 1
```